# How to break line in a theorem when using lists?

Tags: lists, theorems

I have defined my theorem style as:

```
\newtheoremstyle{ejemplo} % Style name
{2ex} % Above space
{2ex} % Below space
{\normalfont} % Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\bfseries} % Head font
{} % Post head punctuation
{\newline} % Post head space
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}:\thmnote{ [#3]}} % Head spec
```

However when I use it in combination with lists like this:

```
\begin{obs}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla bla bla 
\item Bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{obs}
```

I do not get the new line. The problem is resolved if I add something before the lists:

```
\begin{obs}
This fixes it
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla bla bla 
\item Bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{obs}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

---

**Edit:** Sorry. Here's the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{memoir}

% Packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{ejemplo} % Style name
{2ex} % Above space
{2ex} % Below space
{\normalfont} % Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\bfseries} % Head font
{} % Post head punctuation
{\newline} % Post head space
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}:\thmnote{ [#3]}} % Head spec

\theoremstyle{ejemplo}
\newtheorem*{obs}{Observación}


\begin{document}

\begin{obs}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla bla bla 
\item Bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{obs}

\begin{obs}
This fixes it
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla bla bla 
\item Bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{obs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Answer (score 3):

I propose to define a new `thmenum` enumerate-like list, adapted to a theorem-like environment, with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{memoir}

% Packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{thmenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmenum]{label=\arabic*., itemsep=2pt, before=\leavevmode}

\newtheoremstyle{ejemplo} % Style name
{2ex} % Above space
{2ex} % Below space
{\normalfont} % Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\bfseries} % Head font
{} % Post head punctuation
{1em} % Post head space
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}:\thmnote{ [#3]}} % Head spec

\theoremstyle{ejemplo}
\newtheorem*{obs}{Observación}

\begin{document}

\begin{obs}
\begin{thmenum}
\item Bla bla bla
\item Bla bla bla
\end{thmenum}
\end{obs}

\begin{obs}
This fixes it
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bla bla bla
\item Bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{obs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But it seems to damage the behavior when I write something before the list, as in the second part (the one with "this fixes it"). I would like to have everything, except for the optional description of the theorem, below the header. Should I define two theorem styles or is it possible to have it all in one?

Comment: If there's text before the list, use  an ordinary `enumerate` – `thmenum` is intended for the case the theorem body starts with a list.

Comment: Does this mean that instead of `thmenum` and `This fixes it`, OP could use `\leavevmode`?

Comment: @Teepeemm: Yes – I simply found better, semantically, to define a dedicated list.